# How to deploy two copies of nginx ingress in kubernetes?

Tags: nginx, kubernetes-ingress, nginx-reverse-proxy, nginx-ingress

i have two servcies exposed over nginx which are sentry and keycloak, both of them get redirected to the same url (/auth/login) since keycloak is only accessible over /auth (i'm not allowed to change it) and sentry cannot be exposed over subpath. so i thought that running two nginx ingress controllers with two different internal URLs (xxxxx-xxxx.elb.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com)could solve my problem. So my question is how two deploy two nginx ingress controllers with the same class (nginx) and how to identify each one in any Ingress object (like adding an annotation).

Here is nginx ingress controller yaml file :

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Namespace
metadata:
  name: ingress-nginx
  labels:
    app.kubernetes.io/name: ingress-nginx
    app.kubernetes.io/instance: ingress-nginx

---
# Source: ingress-nginx/templates/controller-serviceaccount.yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: ServiceAccount
metadata:
  labels:
    helm.sh/chart: ingress-nginx-2.0.1
    app.kubernetes.io/name: ingress-nginx
    app.kubernetes.io/instance: ingress-nginx
    app.kubernetes.io/version: 0.31.1
    app.kubernetes.io/managed-by: Helm
    app.kubernetes.io/component: controller
  name: ingress-nginx
  namespace: ingress-nginx
---
# Source: ingress-nginx/templates/controller-configmap.yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  labels:
    helm.sh/chart: ingress-nginx-2.0.1
    app.kubernetes.io/name: ingress-nginx
    app.kubernetes.io/instance: ingress-nginx
    app.kubernetes.io/version: 0.31.1
    app.kubernetes.io/managed-by: Helm
    app.kubernetes.io/component: controller
  name: ingress-nginx-controller
  namespace: ingress-nginx
data:
---
# Source: ingress-nginx/templates/clusterrole.yaml
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: ClusterRole
metadata:
  labels:
    helm.sh/chart: ingress-nginx-2.0.1
    app.kubernetes.io/name: ingress-nginx
    app.kubernetes.io/instance: ingress-nginx
    app.kubernetes.io/version: 0.31.1
    app.kubernetes.io/managed-by: Helm
  name: ingress-nginx
  namespace: ingress-nginx
rules:
  - apiGroups:
      - ''
    resources:
      - configmaps
      - endpoints
      - nodes
      - pods
      - secrets
    verbs:
      - list
      - watch
  - apiGroups:
      - ''
    resources:
      - nodes
    verbs:
      - get
  - apiGroups:
      - ''
    resources:
      - services
    verbs:
      - get
      - list
      - update
      - watch
  - apiGroups:
      - extensions
      - networking.k8s.io   # k8s 1.14+
    resources:
      - ingresses
    verbs:
      - get
      - list
      - watch
  - apiGroups:
      - ''
    resources:
      - events
    verbs:
      - create
      - patch
  - apiGroups:
      - extensions
      - networking.k8s.io   # k8s 1.14+
    resources:
      - ingresses/status
    verbs:
      - update
  - apiGroups:
      - networking.k8s.io   # k8s 1.14+
    resources:
      - ingressclasses
    verbs:
      - get
      - list
      - watch
---
# Source: ingress-nginx/templates/clusterrolebinding.yaml
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: ClusterRoleBinding
metadata:
  labels:
    helm.sh/chart: ingress-nginx-2.0.1
    app.kubernetes.io/name: ingress-nginx
    app.kubernetes.io/instance: ingress-nginx
    app.kubernetes.io/version: 0.31.1
    app.kubernetes.io/managed-by: Helm
  name: ingress-nginx
  namespace: ingress-nginx
roleRef:
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
  kind: ClusterRole
  name: ingress-nginx
subjects:
  - kind: ServiceAccount
    name: ingress-nginx
    namespace: ingress-nginx
---
# Source: ingress-nginx/templates/controller-role.yaml
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: Role
metadata:
  labels:
    helm.sh/chart: ingress-nginx-2.0.1
    app.kubernetes.io/name: ingress-nginx
    app.kubernetes.io/instance: ingress-nginx
    app.kubernetes.io/version: 0.31.1
    app.kubernetes.io/managed-by: Helm
    app.kubernetes.io/component: controller
  name: ingress-nginx
  namespace: ingress-nginx
rules:
  - apiGroups:
      - ''
    resources:
      - namespaces
    verbs:
      - get
  - apiGroups:
      - ''
    resources:
      - configmaps
      - pods
      - secrets
      - endpoints
    verbs:
      - get
      - list
      - watch
  - apiGroups:
      - ''
    resources:
      - services
    verbs:
      - get
      - list
      - update
      - watch
  - apiGroups:
      - extensions
      - networking.k8s.io   # k8s 1.14+
    resources:
      - ingresses
    verbs:
      - get
      - list
      - watch
  - apiGroups:
      - extensions
      - networking.k8s.io   # k8s 1.14+
    resources:
      - ingresses/status
    verbs:
      - update
  - apiGroups:
      - networking.k8s.io   # k8s 1.14+
    resources:
      - ingressclasses
    verbs:
      - get
      - list
      - watch
  - apiGroups:
      - ''
    resources:
      - configmaps
    resourceNames:
      - ingress-controller-leader-nginx
    verbs:
      - get
      - update
  - apiGroups:
      - ''
    resources:
      - configmaps
    verbs:
      - create
  - apiGroups:
      - ''
    resources:
      - endpoints
    verbs:
      - create
      - get
      - update
  - apiGroups:
      - ''
    resources:
      - events
    verbs:
      - create
      - patch
---
# Source: ingress-nginx/templates/controller-rolebinding.yaml
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: RoleBinding
metadata:
  labels:
    helm.sh/chart: ingress-nginx-2.0.1
    app.kubernetes.io/name: ingress-nginx
    app.kubernetes.io/instance: ingress-nginx
    app.kubernetes.io/version: 0.31.1
    app.kubernetes.io/managed-by: Helm
    app.kubernetes.io/component: controller
  name: ingress-nginx
  namespace: ingress-nginx
roleRef:
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
  kind: Role
  name: ingress-nginx
subjects:
  - kind: ServiceAccount
    name: ingress-nginx
    namespace: ingress-nginx
---
# Source: ingress-nginx/templates/controller-service-webhook.yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  labels:
    helm.sh/chart: ingress-nginx-2.0.1
    app.kubernetes.io/name: ingress-nginx
    app.kubernetes.io/instance: ingress-nginx
    app.kubernetes.io/version: 0.31.1
    app.kubernetes.io/managed-by: Helm
    app.kubernetes.io/component: controller
  name: ingress-nginx-controller-admission
  namespace: ingress-nginx
spec:
  type: ClusterIP
  ports:
    - name: https-webhook
      port: 443
      targetPort: webhook
  selector:
    app.kubernetes.io/name: ingress-nginx
    app.kubernetes.io/instance: ingress-nginx
    app.kubernetes.io/component: controller
---
# Source: ingress-nginx/templates/controller-service.yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  annotations:
    service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-backend-protocol: tcp
    service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-connection-idle-timeout: '60'
    service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-cross-zone-load-balancing-enabled: 'true'
    service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-type: nlb
    service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-internal: "true"
  labels:
    helm.sh/chart: ingress-nginx-2.0.1
    app.kubernetes.io/name: ingress-nginx
    app.kubernetes.io/instance: ingress-nginx
    app.kubernetes.io/version: 0.31.1
    app.kubernetes.io/managed-by: Helm
    app.kubernetes.io/component: controller
  name: ingress-nginx-controller
  namespace: ingress-nginx
spec:
  type: LoadBalancer
  externalTrafficPolicy: Local
  ports:
    - name: http
      port: 80
      protocol: TCP
      targetPort: http
    - name: https
      port: 443
      protocol: TCP
      targetPort: https
  selector:
    app.kubernetes.io/name: ingress-nginx
    app.kubernetes.io/instance: ingress-nginx
    app.kubernetes.io/component: controller
---
# Source: ingress-nginx/templates/controller-deployment.yaml
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  labels:
    helm.sh/chart: ingress-nginx-2.0.1
    app.kubernetes.io/name: ingress-nginx
    app.kubernetes.io/instance: ingress-nginx
    app.kubernetes.io/version: 0.31.1
    app.kubernetes.io/managed-by: Helm
    app.kubernetes.io/component: controller
  name: ingress-nginx-controller
  namespace: ingress-nginx
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app.kubernetes.io/name: ingress-nginx
      app.kubernetes.io/instance: ingress-nginx
      app.kubernetes.io/component: controller
  revisionHistoryLimit: 10
  minReadySeconds: 0
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app.kubernetes.io/name: ingress-nginx
        app.kubernetes.io/instance: ingress-nginx
        app.kubernetes.io/component: controller
    spec:
      dnsPolicy: ClusterFirst
      containers:
        - name: controller
          image: quay.io/kubernetes-ingress-controller/nginx-ingress-controller:0.31.1
          imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
          lifecycle:
            preStop:
              exec:
                command:
                  - /wait-shutdown
          args:
            - /nginx-ingress-controller
            - --publish-service=ingress-nginx/ingress-nginx-controller
            - --election-id=ingress-controller-leader
            - --ingress-class=nginx
            - --configmap=ingress-nginx/ingress-nginx-controller
            - --validating-webhook=:8443
            - --validating-webhook-certificate=/usr/local/certificates/cert
            - --validating-webhook-key=/usr/local/certificates/key
          securityContext:
            capabilities:
              drop:
                - ALL
              add:
                - NET_BIND_SERVICE
            runAsUser: 101
            allowPrivilegeEscalation: true
          env:
            - name: POD_NAME
              valueFrom:
                fieldRef:
                  fieldPath: metadata.name
            - name: POD_NAMESPACE
              valueFrom:
                fieldRef:
                  fieldPath: metadata.namespace
          livenessProbe:
            httpGet:
              path: /healthz
              port: 10254
              scheme: HTTP
            initialDelaySeconds: 10
            periodSeconds: 10
            timeoutSeconds: 1
            successThreshold: 1
            failureThreshold: 3
          readinessProbe:
            httpGet:
              path: /healthz
              port: 10254
              scheme: HTTP
            initialDelaySeconds: 10
            periodSeconds: 10
            timeoutSeconds: 1
            successThreshold: 1
            failureThreshold: 3
          ports:
            - name: http
              containerPort: 80
              protocol: TCP
            - name: https
              containerPort: 443
              protocol: TCP
            - name: webhook
              containerPort: 8443
              protocol: TCP
          volumeMounts:
            - name: webhook-cert
              mountPath: /usr/local/certificates/
              readOnly: true
          resources:
            requests:
              cpu: 100m
              memory: 90Mi
      serviceAccountName: ingress-nginx
      terminationGracePeriodSeconds: 300
      volumes:
        - name: webhook-cert
          secret:
            secretName: ingress-nginx-admission
---
# Source: ingress-nginx/templates/admission-webhooks/validating-webhook.yaml
apiVersion: admissionregistration.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: ValidatingWebhookConfiguration
metadata:
  labels:
    helm.sh/chart: ingress-nginx-2.0.1
    app.kubernetes.io/name: ingress-nginx
    app.kubernetes.io/instance: ingress-nginx
    app.kubernetes.io/version: 0.31.1
    app.kubernetes.io/managed-by: Helm
    app.kubernetes.io/component: admission-webhook
  name: ingress-nginx-admission
  namespace: ingress-nginx
webhooks:
  - name: validate.nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io
    rules:
      - apiGroups:
          - extensions
          - networking.k8s.io
        apiVersions:
          - v1beta1
        operations:
          - CREATE
          - UPDATE
        resources:
          - ingresses
    failurePolicy: Fail
    clientConfig:
      service:
        namespace: ingress-nginx
        name: ingress-nginx-controller-admission
        path: /extensions/v1beta1/ingresses
---
# Source: ingress-nginx/templates/admission-webhooks/job-patch/clusterrole.yaml
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: ClusterRole
metadata:
  name: ingress-nginx-admission
  annotations:
    helm.sh/hook: pre-install,pre-upgrade,post-install,post-upgrade
    helm.sh/hook-delete-policy: before-hook-creation,hook-succeeded
  labels:
    helm.sh/chart: ingress-nginx-2.0.1
    app.kubernetes.io/name: ingress-nginx
    app.kubernetes.io/instance: ingress-nginx
    app.kubernetes.io/version: 0.31.1
    app.kubernetes.io/managed-by: Helm
    app.kubernetes.io/component: admission-webhook
  namespace: ingress-nginx
rules:
  - apiGroups:
      - admissionregistration.k8s.io
    resources:
      - validatingwebhookconfigurations
    verbs:
      - get
      - update
---
# Source: ingress-nginx/templates/admission-webhooks/job-patch/clusterrolebinding.yaml
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: ClusterRoleBinding
metadata:
  name: ingress-nginx-admission
  annotations:
    helm.sh/hook: pre-install,pre-upgrade,post-install,post-upgrade
    helm.sh/hook-delete-policy: before-hook-creation,hook-succeeded
  labels:
    helm.sh/chart: ingress-nginx-2.0.1
    app.kubernetes.io/name: ingress-nginx
    app.kubernetes.io/instance: ingress-nginx
    app.kubernetes.io/version: 0.31.1
    app.kubernetes.io/managed-by: Helm
    app.kubernetes.io/component: admission-webhook
  namespace: ingress-nginx
roleRef:
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
  kind: ClusterRole
  name: ingress-nginx-admission
subjects:
  - kind: ServiceAccount
    name: ingress-nginx-admission
    namespace: ingress-nginx
---
# Source: ingress-nginx/templates/admission-webhooks/job-patch/job-createSecret.yaml
apiVersion: batch/v1
kind: Job
metadata:
  name: ingress-nginx-admission-create
  annotations:
    helm.sh/hook: pre-install,pre-upgrade
    helm.sh/hook-delete-policy: before-hook-creation,hook-succeeded
  labels:
    helm.sh/chart: ingress-nginx-2.0.1
    app.kubernetes.io/name: ingress-nginx
    app.kubernetes.io/instance: ingress-nginx
    app.kubernetes.io/version: 0.31.1
    app.kubernetes.io/managed-by: Helm
    app.kubernetes.io/component: admission-webhook
  namespace: ingress-nginx
spec:
  template:
    metadata:
      name: ingress-nginx-admission-create
      labels:
        helm.sh/chart: ingress-nginx-2.0.1
        app.kubernetes.io/name: ingress-nginx
        app.kubernetes.io/instance: ingress-nginx
        app.kubernetes.io/version: 0.31.1
        app.kubernetes.io/managed-by: Helm
        app.kubernetes.io/component: admission-webhook
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: create
          image: jettech/kube-webhook-certgen:v1.0.0
          imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
          args:
            - create
            - --host=ingress-nginx-controller-admission,ingress-nginx-controller-admission.ingress-nginx.svc
            - --namespace=ingress-nginx
            - --secret-name=ingress-nginx-admission
      restartPolicy: OnFailure
      serviceAccountName: ingress-nginx-admission
      securityContext:
        runAsNonRoot: true
        runAsUser: 2000
---
# Source: ingress-nginx/templates/admission-webhooks/job-patch/job-patchWebhook.yaml
apiVersion: batch/v1
kind: Job
metadata:
  name: ingress-nginx-admission-patch
  annotations:
    helm.sh/hook: post-install,post-upgrade
    helm.sh/hook-delete-policy: before-hook-creation,hook-succeeded
  labels:
    helm.sh/chart: ingress-nginx-2.0.1
    app.kubernetes.io/name: ingress-nginx
    app.kubernetes.io/instance: ingress-nginx
    app.kubernetes.io/version: 0.31.1
    app.kubernetes.io/managed-by: Helm
    app.kubernetes.io/component: admission-webhook
  namespace: ingress-nginx
spec:
  template:
    metadata:
      name: ingress-nginx-admission-patch
      labels:
        helm.sh/chart: ingress-nginx-2.0.1
        app.kubernetes.io/name: ingress-nginx
        app.kubernetes.io/instance: ingress-nginx
        app.kubernetes.io/version: 0.31.1
        app.kubernetes.io/managed-by: Helm
        app.kubernetes.io/component: admission-webhook
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: patch
          image: jettech/kube-webhook-certgen:v1.0.0
          imagePullPolicy:
          args:
            - patch
            - --webhook-name=ingress-nginx-admission
            - --namespace=ingress-nginx
            - --patch-mutating=false
            - --secret-name=ingress-nginx-admission
            - --patch-failure-policy=Fail
      restartPolicy: OnFailure
      serviceAccountName: ingress-nginx-admission
      securityContext:
        runAsNonRoot: true
        runAsUser: 2000
---
# Source: ingress-nginx/templates/admission-webhooks/job-patch/role.yaml
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: Role
metadata:
  name: ingress-nginx-admission
  annotations:
    helm.sh/hook: pre-install,pre-upgrade,post-install,post-upgrade
    helm.sh/hook-delete-policy: before-hook-creation,hook-succeeded
  labels:
    helm.sh/chart: ingress-nginx-2.0.1
    app.kubernetes.io/name: ingress-nginx
    app.kubernetes.io/instance: ingress-nginx
    app.kubernetes.io/version: 0.31.1
    app.kubernetes.io/managed-by: Helm
    app.kubernetes.io/component: admission-webhook
  namespace: ingress-nginx
rules:
  - apiGroups:
      - ''
    resources:
      - secrets
    verbs:
      - get
      - create
---
# Source: ingress-nginx/templates/admission-webhooks/job-patch/rolebinding.yaml
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: RoleBinding
metadata:
  name: ingress-nginx-admission
  annotations:
    helm.sh/hook: pre-install,pre-upgrade,post-install,post-upgrade
    helm.sh/hook-delete-policy: before-hook-creation,hook-succeeded
  labels:
    helm.sh/chart: ingress-nginx-2.0.1
    app.kubernetes.io/name: ingress-nginx
    app.kubernetes.io/instance: ingress-nginx
    app.kubernetes.io/version: 0.31.1
    app.kubernetes.io/managed-by: Helm
    app.kubernetes.io/component: admission-webhook
  namespace: ingress-nginx
roleRef:
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
  kind: Role
  name: ingress-nginx-admission
subjects:
  - kind: ServiceAccount
    name: ingress-nginx-admission
    namespace: ingress-nginx
---
# Source: ingress-nginx/templates/admission-webhooks/job-patch/serviceaccount.yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: ServiceAccount
metadata:
  name: ingress-nginx-admission
  annotations:
    helm.sh/hook: pre-install,pre-upgrade,post-install,post-upgrade
    helm.sh/hook-delete-policy: before-hook-creation,hook-succeeded
  labels:
    helm.sh/chart: ingress-nginx-2.0.1
    app.kubernetes.io/name: ingress-nginx
    app.kubernetes.io/instance: ingress-nginx
    app.kubernetes.io/version: 0.31.1
    app.kubernetes.io/managed-by: Helm
    app.kubernetes.io/component: admission-webhook
  namespace: ingress-nginx
```

Comment: you better think something else. Having two nginx ingress controllers in the cluster for this scenario is a terrible idea.

Comment: do you have any other suggestion ?

Comment: you seem to have lots of limitations. To try to fix application limitations with kubernetes usually end up in these kind of cumbersome configurations. Like this one can't be exposed like this, the other one only can be accessed through that. By the way, no one needs nginx ingress controller yaml. Its on their GitHub.

Answer (score 1):

This looks like something you could solve with virtual hosts.

Point multiple domains/subdomains in the DNS config to your nginx-ingress IP. Then you can create multiple ingresses with different `host` values. When visiting one subdomain, nginx will check all ingresses and send the traffic to the one with the matching `host`. This way you can deploy an unlimited number of apps, each on their own subdomain, and you won't have path conflicts.

I don't recommend it, but if you really, really want to run 2 ingress controllers, you can do so.

The trick is to configure them differently, so each one responds to a different "ingress class".

- Change `ingress-class` in the two ingress controller deployments to different values: `--ingress-class=nginx-foo`
- Add annotation `kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "nginx-foo"` to ingresses you want to take effect in the `nginx-foo` ingress controller.

more info [here](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/user-guide/multiple-ingress/#multiple-ingress-nginx-controllers)

Comment: thank but i want to know should i duplicate the deployment and service of ingress controller or the other resources also (configmap, serviceAccount, ...)?

Comment: Either change the names of everything (add a suffix like `-foo`)  for example, or deploy them in a different namespace (k8s objects with same name are still different objects if they're in different namespaces). The namespace option is probably more manageable.